# Recursive list s3 bucket contents with AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

How can I recursively list all all the contents of a bucket using the AWS CLI similar to using `find .` on Unix.

`aws s3 ls s3://MyBucket --recursive` complains with unknown option.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html#directory-and-s3-prefix-operations claims that `--recursive` is a valid parameter.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

`aws s3 ls s3://MyBucket --recursive` works fine for me.

Try updating your AWS CLI. My version is aws-cli/1.6.2

`aws --version`

Comment: Original question was from a while ago with version 1.3.X

Answer (score 4):

With recent **AWS CLI** versions, `--recursive` option is supported.

You can list recursively all the files under a bucket named **MyBucket** using following command:

```
aws s3 ls s3://MyBucket/ --recursive
```

You can list recursively all the files under a folder named **MyFolder** in the bucket, using following command:

```
aws s3 ls s3://MyBucket/MyFolder/ --recursive
```

*As @Francisco Cardoso said, the final `/` is very important. It allows to list the content of the folder instead of the folder itself*

For more information, see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/ls.html

Comment: That final "/" after MyFolder is very important

Answer (score 1):

I am not able to interpret the link you referred properly: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html#directory-and-s3-prefix-operations

However, I was able to make `--recursive` option work with respect to this link: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html#single-local-file-and-s3-object-operations

as per this link, `cp`, `mv` and `rm` supports `--recursive` option.

The one that you are trying is `ls`.

I tried using `cp` and `rm` with `--recursive` option and it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can not list recursively all the contents of a bucket via -

```
aws s3 ls s3://MyBucket
```

To list object from a folder you need to execute command as -

```
aws s3 ls s3://MyBucket/MyFolder/
```

This above command lists object that reside inside folder named **MyFolder**.

To get an objects list from such a logical hierarchy from Amazon S3, you need specify the full key name for the object in the [GET operation](http://www.bucketexplorer.com/documentation/amazon-s3--download-s3-objects-in-a-single-operation-get-object-download.html).

--recursive [Command](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html#single-local-file-and-s3-object-operations) is performed on allfiles or objects under the specified directory or prefix.

Thanks

Comment: This is no longer true.

Comment: best to delete obsolete info

Comment: Is there a way to get only file names and not timestamps, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Below one line bash script is able to perform:- how to list all S3 buckets with their objects recursively, list bucket name and count objects also.

```
/usr/bin/sudo /usr/local/bin/aws s3 ls |awk '{print $NF}'| while read l;do echo -e "#######---$l objects---##########\n\n";/usr/bin/sudo /usr/local/bin/aws s3 ls $l|nl;done
```